# How do I automate removing lines from a multiline textbox while moving it to another multiline textbox in Visual Basic .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-11

I have two multiline textboxes; txtInputList and txtComplete. I can manually move a line from txtInputList to txtComplete while removing the line from txtInputList as the desired result. However, I am having difficulty in automating this for every line. Here is the manual way clicking the button for each line:

```
Private Sub btnProcessItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcessItems.Click
    Dim strText() As String
    strText = Split(txtInputList.Text, vbCrLf)
    txtInputList.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, strText, 1, strText.Length - 1)
    txtComplete.AppendText(strText(0) + vbCrLf)
End Sub
```

That works as desired. I've tried a For-loop, but I can't get it to work.

```
Private Sub btnProcessItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcessItems.Click
    Dim strText() As String
    strText = Split(txtInputList.Text, vbCrLf)
    For x As Integer = 0 to strText.Length
        txtInputList.Text = String.Join(vbCrLf, strText, 1, strText.Length - 1)
        txtComplete.AppendText(strText(0) + vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

Can someone please help? Thank you!

Comment: txt2 = txt1, txt1 = "", why do you need to iterate anything?

Comment: I'm talking hundreds of sites at a time. I will be iterating through a list of websites and changing servers and such. When I click the Process button, I need it to grab a site, do its processing, move the name to the completed list and remove it from the InputList. I can do it one line at a time by pressing the process button for each line. I want to press the Process button and have it go through all of them.

Comment: Critical to the question. Include it

Answer (score 1):

Don't keep your data on your UI. Use a data structure to keep your data so you can operate on it directly (off the UI thread) then update the UI with the state of your data. If your data is just a list of strings then use `List(Of String)` or if it is more than just strings, use a `List(Of someClass)`.

My answer will fix a number of issues for you.

1. Keep data in a list
2. Process data off the UI thread
3. Use Async/Await to ensure no UI blocking

First, a class to hold the data. You have the option for a nice name for display, and a Url or whatever other property you want to use in your processor

```
Public Class Data
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Sub New(name As String)
        Me.Name = name
    End Sub
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

Make lists of input items and complete items, and I will initialize inputs with 10 items, with letters A ... J. Also define a method to put both lists into your TextBoxes

```
Private inputs As List(Of Data)
Private completes As List(Of Data)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' initialize our fake data
    inputs = Enumerable.Range(65, 10).Select(Function(i) New Data(New String({Chr(i)}))).ToList()
    completes = New List(Of Data)()
    bindTextBoxes()
End Sub

Private Sub bindTextBoxes()
    txtInputList.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, inputs)
    txtComplete.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, completes)
End Sub
```

[image]

Add an Async button handler to process all items, and Task function to process each item. The button handler doesn't process anything, rather it's handled in the Awaited task. After each item is handled, you rebind the TextBoxes to update the UI.

```
Private Async Sub btnProcessItems_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnProcessItems.Click
    While inputs.Any()
        Await processFirstItem()
        bindTextBoxes()
    End While
End Sub

Private Function processFirstItem() As Task
    Return Task.Run(
        Sub()
            Dim item = inputs.First()
            inputs.RemoveAt(0)
            processItem(item)
            completes.Add(item)
        End Sub)
End Function

Private Sub processItem(item As Data)
    ' do whatever you need to do on the item, emulate a delay with thread sleep
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(250) ' remove this in production
End Sub
```

You may notice if you try this code that it runs off the UI so your app will run smoothly. You are just acting on a data structure instead of the UI. This is one good way to do what you are trying to do.

[image]

If your processing can be done in parallel, then you should look into [Task Parallel Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl), and your work will probably be performed much faster depending on the resources being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you'll need to change the names of the textboxes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
        sb.AppendLine(line)
    Next
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Text = sb.ToString
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally agree with djv's answer, but here's one way to do it directly with the UI:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If TextBox1.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Button1.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Enabled = False
    TextBox2.Enabled = False
    TextBox2.Clear()

    Dim lines As New List(Of String)(TextBox1.Lines)
    Dim processed As New List(Of String)
    While (lines.Count > 0)
        Dim current As String = lines(0)
        lines.RemoveAt(0)
        TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray


        ' ... do something with "current" ...
        Label1.Text = "Processing: " & current
        Await Task.Delay(2000)

        processed.Add(current)
        TextBox2.Lines = processed.ToArray
    End While
    Label1.Text = ""

    TextBox1.Enabled = True
    TextBox2.Enabled = True
    Button1.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Here it is in action:

[image]